# Searching documents by tag using the Scribd API is no longer returning expected results

Tags: php, api, search, tags, scribd

Recently I have encountered an issue with Scribd where searching via Scribd API (docs.search) for documents by tag is no longer working.

This has been working (for over 6 months) to return a number of documents that I have tagged with "fdsafetyandprevention" (accessible here http://www.scribd.com/tag/fdsafetyandprevention). Just recently my search via the API has stopped working.

Note that test searches such as @tags "selfhelp" as described in the Scribd documentation DO work. Could my issue be related to caching or the age of my documents and Scribd choosing to not return them in search results?

I have been using scribd.php (http://www.scribd.com/developers/libraries) to interface with the API using $scribd->search(@tags "fdsafetyandprevention", 20, 0, "all").

I am following the Scribd documentation for docs.search and advanced help (http://www.scribd.com/developers/search_help).

Help greatly appreciated.

George.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's been some instability in Scribd's search architecture in the last few days which is what's causing your problem.

We're working to fix everything up.